# C# Bitwise Operator With Ints

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

What does this expression actually mean??

Note - the x and y vars are just sample values.

```
int x = 3; 
int y = 1; 

if ((x & y) !=0)
```

I inherited a codebase and am not up to speed on bitwise operators. I have read up, but am still missing something. Help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's comparing the bits in each value.  It returns any bits that are set in both numbers.

In your example:

```
    3:  0011
    1:  0001

3 & 1:  0001
```

Answer (score 2):

This checks whether x and y both have at least one common bit set. In the case of your example this would be the true.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ((x & y) != 0)
```

This would typically be used to determine whether the value `x` has a specific bit-flag (`y`) set. The AND operator returns an integer with only those bits set that are set in both operands.