# Strange results when & is used in conjunction of two integers C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am not able to understand whats happening and how this result from the following lines:

Example 1: I get *1* as result for the below.

```
int a = 1, b = 9;
int r = a & b;
Console.WriteLine(r);
```

Example 2: I get *8* as result for the below.

```
int a = 10, b = 9;
int r = a & b;
Console.WriteLine(r);
```

I don't know the significance of `&` and the significance of `&` in this context. How the results above are manipulated? Whats the logic?

Comment: I wonder what it is you are trying to do here. What results did you expect?

Comment: lol I took an online exam and there was a question, so I tried it in VS, I got the results, I dont know whats the logic of results. Thats why i asked here :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Bitwise arithmetic:

```
9 = 1001       9 = 1001
1 = 0001      10 = 1010
--------      ---------
& = 0001 = 1   & = 1000 = 8
```

where `&` follows the truth-table (per-bit):

```
& | 0 1
--+----
0 | 0 0
1 | 0 1
```

i.e. "outputs 1 only if both inputs are 1"

Comment: Thank you Marc :) It helps me  a lot

Comment: But I have a question. how do we know the truth table for & is this ? Also whats the truth table for or operator ? I think its represented by || ?

Comment: @Divine the bitwise "or" is `|`, not `||`; "or" is "outputs 1 if either or both inputs are 1", so `{0,0}=>0`, `{1,0}=>1`, `{0,1}=>1`, `{1,1}=>1`. As for "how do we know the truth table" - either by understanding the reasoning (i.e. "outputs 1 only if both inputs are 1") and **figuring it out**, or by another trick, called "learning it". The "understanding the reasoning" approach is far more useful, IMO. For example, "xor" is "outputs 1 if *exactly* one (i.e. not both) of the inputs are 1", etc

Answer (score 2):

From [`& Operator (C# Reference)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> For integral types, `&` computes the **logical bitwise AND** of its
>   operands.

Truth table for `&`

```
& | 0 1
--+----
0 | 0 0
1 | 0 1
```

When you write `1 & 9` result will be `1` because it works like;

```
0001
1001

x---------------
0001
```

When you write `10 & 9` result will be `8` because it works like;

```
1010
1001

x---------------
1000
```

Comment: :).........................

Answer (score 1):

It is [Bitwise `&` (AND)](http://www.dotnetperls.com/and) operator.

> The bitwise and operator changes bits. It provides important
>   functionality for bitwise logic. When it is applied to two numbers,
>   the result is another number that contains a 1 where each of the two
>   numbers also have a 1.

Also see:[& Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

For you case where 
int a = 1, b = 9;
int r = a & b;

```
a: 0001 (binary equvivalent of 1)
b: 1001 (binary equvivalent of 9)
----------
r: 0001 (which would be 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491419/c-sharp-bitwise-operator-with-ints) is a sample:

```
    3:  0011
    1:  0001

3 & 1:  0001
```

Answer (score 0):

int r = a & b; // a = 1, b = 9

1st example:

```
a: 0 0 0 1
b: 1 0 0 1

r: 0 0 0 1  // 1
```

2nd example:

```
a: 1 0 1 0
b: 1 0 0 1

r: 1 0 0 0  // 8
```

& (AND-operator) means, that the result (r) is only 1 when a and b are 1. Otherwise it's 0.

Comment: Thank you, but a is only 1 and b is not 1, you say "when and and b" should be 1 for r to be 1. How :0 And how did you compute the binary division of a/b ?